# Storing a Go project with other non-Go projects

Tags: go

When it comes to code organization, Go seem to make an assumption, that it's the only language I'm going to use. However, I'd like to treat each Go project as a yet another isolated piece of software, and store it the same way as most programs were stored for decades now - in an arbitrary directory, containing no less and no more than what is needed to build and run it.

What Go wants:

```
home/
├─go/
│ └─src/
│   └─some-organization/
│     └─some-go-project/
│       └─main.go
└─projects/
  └─some-organization/
    ├─some-c-project/
    │ └─src/
    │   └─main.c
    └─some-python-project/
      └─src/
        └─main.py
```

What I want:

```
home/
└─projects/
  └─some-organization/
    ├─some-c-project/
    │ └─src/
    │   └─main.c
    ├─some-python-project/
    │ └─src/
    │   └─main.py
    └─some-go-project/
      └─src/
        └─main.go
```

Of course, nobody prevents me from structuring it my way, but I won't be able to build/install that project the intended way anymore. Doing something like `home/projects/some-organization/some-go-project/src/some-go-project/main.go` to address that is just too ugly to my liking.

So what's the consensus here? How does Go community handle this? Back-to-make?

Comment: Yeah, that is a pain. I normally create the latter structure on disk, and then symlink the go projects into the `GOPATH`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and tried the following solutions (in chronological order):

- *don't put you package in the `$GOPATH` and compile from your project directory*: that works while you have a single-package project. Anyway, go project should have a limited number of package…
- *use a symlink from your project directory to your `$GOPATH`*: it's really boring to have to symlink everytime you want to checkout a new project. More, the various tools asking for a package name (fmt, test, etc) won't find your package, unless you make the link the other way around, which is equally boring (even more, as it defies your git layout).
- *add a `$GOPATH` entry for each project (like `$PATH`)*: even more boring than the previous solution, but mostly works. Even better if your poject layout is based on a `src/` directory.
- *use vagrant and a dedicated `$GOPATH`*: you can work as intended by golang, with the added complexity of having to ssh into the box. That's what I am doing now, as it have the benefits of vagrant as a bonus.

Comment: I've ended up doing what you're doing with Vagrant, but with Docker instead, which is a trivial task, actually. Cumbersome to setup for the first time, but works well.

Comment: Now that I've spent some time dealing with Go, I still wasn't completely happy with with my workflow / resulting structure, so I began looking again. I was aware of various package managers, like `gpm` + `gvp`, `godep`, but they weren't quite cutting it. And then I found [`glide`](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide). Have been using it for a couple of days now, and it does exactly what I need: lets me store my sources wherever I want to, isolates the environment like `virtualenv` in Python, and, as an extra, provides a way to pinpoint dependencies (custom repo, branch, version). Good stuff.

Answer (score 4):

This is a complicated issue and a huge headache, but what I did to solve this issue was to do it the other way around:

```
home/
└─projects/
  ├bin/
  ├pkg/ 
  └─src/
    └─some-organization/
      ├─some-go-project/
      |  └─main.go
      ├─some-c-project/
      │ └─main.c
      └─some-python-project/
        └─main.py
```

And I use the go `bin` and `pkg` directories for binaries and libraries of all languages. The go layout is not bad, is just different and having your go code in a 'special' structure different from all your other code is kind of ugly so I prefer to adopt the go directory structure for all my projects.

As an upside, you have all your software projects classified by repo hosting site and that is nice.